# Test cases for the below function

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I am not familiar with unit tests but I came across this question in an Interview. Can anyone help me with some unit test cases and explain their output. I know that we just need to pass the parameters but any negative cases?

Unit test a function which uses the following parameters:
`reverseString(originalString, stringToBeReversed, stringReverseTo, max)`

Comment: Pass the null String to it.

Comment: Could you explain what the different arguments mean? stringToBeReversed I understand, but what about the others. Other than that the test could use nulls, negative indexes and too large indexes.

Comment: you mean to say reversestring('','','', ). So the output is null, will that come as negative case?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö yes everything can be used.

Comment: being an interview question, I suppose you came with a response of your own. Would you be kind enough to share your output?

Comment: @user503413 Some cases which came to my mind are: reversestring('abcde', 'abc', 'cba', 3) reversestring(123456, 33, 55, 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reversestring(originalString, stringToBeReversed, stringReverseTo, max)
```

You will need a matrix for the test cases, you will have to test each combination for the string parameters of empty strings, nulls, depending on the implementation evtl. strings which contain non english values.

For the integer parameter a negative, zero and positive numbers, depending on what the max means maby you should test a big number which exceeds the maximum linit if exists.

The things mentioned may have get tested in combination with each other. for example a null original string with a negativ integer, it all depend on the implementation, if you have such a loop which has a combined condition of two parameters then the combination should be tested.